# How to combine 3 validation checks into one loop?

Tags: python

For example I have  a tuple such as

```
tup = [['P Y T F EY EN', 'p y t h o n'], ['R O K', 'r o x']]
```

I then separate the tuple into lists such as

```
lst1 = [['P', 'Y', 'T', 'F', 'EY', 'EN'], ['R', 'O', 'K']]

lst2 = [['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], ['r', 'o', 'x']]
```

The 3 conditions I have are as follows:
First the length of the 1st element in the tuple must be equal to that of the 2nd

```
for i in tup:

    if not len(tup[0].split()) == len(tup[1].split()) : 

        count +=1
        break
```

2nd condition is that for every element in lst1, each character in the element must be in another document such as a csv file

```
for i in lst1:  
    for j in i:
        if j not in file:
            count+=1
            break
```

3rd condition is that every element in lst2, each character must also be in another document

```
for i in lst2: 
    for j in i:
        if j not in other_file:
            count+=1

            break
```

As you can see I want the count to increase each time one of these conditions is broken. I also don't want the counts to overlap and to skip onto the next row if a condition is broken while appending to the count.

Comment: You don't have tuples in your example. Those are all lists.

Comment: What are you expecting `tup[0].split()` to do?

Comment: My mistake Martjin, I'm still quite new to python. tup[0].split() spilits [P Y T F EY EN'] into ['P', 'Y', 'T', 'F', 'EY', 'EN'] and then I compare it with length of ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'] if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

I am assuming the files are small enough to be read all at once:

```
f = open('doc1.csv', 'r') # read all of doc1.csv now
doc1 = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('doc2.csv', 'r') # read all of doc2.csv now
doc2 = f.read()
f.close()

count = 0 # count of all docs that are invalid
for item in tup:
 l1 = item[0].split() # get list version of first and string
 l2 = item[1].split() 
 if len(l1) != len(l2) or not all([char in doc1 for char in l1]) or not all([char in doc2 for char in l2]): # check if lengths are same, if any character in l1 is not in doc1, and any char in l2 is not in doc2 
  count += 1

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two issues with your example:

```
1) tup is a list, not tuple;
2) tup[0] = ['P Y T F EY EN', 'p y t h o n']; tup[1] = ['R O K', 'r o x'];
Both of them are list, and cannot do split()
```

If you would like to calculate the total count, you could do in one statement like the following:

```
print sum([ not len(i[0].split()) == len(i[1].split()) for i in tup ] + \
[ j not in file for j in i for i in lst1 ] + \
[ j not in other_file for j in i for i in lst2 ])
```